# How to make react-select always display the option list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multi-select, react-select

How to make react-select always display the option list 
By default it toggles when you click on the array button or when you start typing something

```html
var Select = require('react-select');

var options = [
  { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];

function logChange(val) {
  console.log('Selected: ', val);
}

<Select
  name="form-field-name"
  value="one"
  options={options}
  onChange={logChange}
/>
```

Comment: Can you please post what you were done?

Comment: added @KevalBhatt

Comment: What output you want?In you question I think it is working fine.

Comment: @ChandrakantThakkar option list should always be visible. 
*Intent - I do not want to use this as a dropDown

Answer (score 11):

Use props
defaultMenuIsOpen
This will make dropdown open by default

```
<Select
  defaultMenuIsOpen
  name="form-field-name"
  value="one"
  options={options}
  onChange={logChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do one thing if you want to show all option without click on select list.

open select on Focus and give default Focus to select on it's mount as bellow.

```
var Select = require('react-select');

var options = [
  { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];

function logChange(val) {
  console.log('Selected: ', val);
}

<Select
  name="form-field-name"
  value="one"
  options={options}
  onChange={logChange}
  openOnFocus={true}
  autofocus={true}
/>
```

After selection of option from list,Selected value will be displayed and others value automatically dropped.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD 2023**

Just use menuIsOpen, defaultMenuIsOpen, menuIsOpen attributes:

```
<Select
 defaultMenuIsOpen
 autoFocus
 menuIsOpen
 ...
/>
```

Comment: Pehaps try adding a link to a working example, you can follow [this guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216465/1094034)

Comment: `menuIsOpen` on its own worked like a charm for me :)